# Where to store Laravel Passport "client_secret" in VueJS

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am a bit new to VueJS and I am using Laravel as API only and VueJS as a separate project.

In my **App.vue**, I have following setup:

> **http://api.com** is my virtual host!

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  created() {
    const postData = {
      grant_type: "password",
      client_id: 2,
      client_secret: 'MvEyvm3MMr0VJ5BlrJyzoKzsjmrVpAXp9FxJHsau',
      username: 'mail@gmail.com',
      password: '**********',
      scope: ''
    }
    axios.post('http://api.com/oauth/token', postData)
    .then(response => {
      const header = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + response.data.access_token,
      };
      axios.get('http://api.com/api/user', { headers: header })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
      })
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

But this file is totally visible to front-end which is not good due to security reasons.

What I did, I made a new route in Laravel as `Route::post('get_client_creds', MyController@index);` and then made a request from `axios` as:

```
axios.post('http://api.com/get_client_creds')
    .then(response => {
        this.client_secret = response.client_secret;
});
```

And but then I thought anyone can also access the route using Postman or may be through console using `axois`, so can someone give me some suggestions about where to store these secrets???
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different ways to specify config settings for `vue`

**#1** `Vue.js` **non-cli** projects, you can use `src/config.js`

1. Create a new file `src/config.js` and add as following

```
  export const API_CLIENT_ID = '123654';
```

2. To use this, try import like:

```
import { API_CLIENT_ID } from '../config'


// in your code
console.log(API_CLIENT_ID);
```

---

**#2** For **Vue CLi projects** follow these steps.

You must use the `.env` files hold the configuration variables.

It could be structured like

```
.env                # loaded in all cases
.env.local          # loaded in all cases, ignored by git
.env.[mode]         # only loaded in specified mode
.env.[mode].local   # only loaded in specified mode, ignored by git
```

Here is how you can specify the variable.

```
FOO=bar
API_CLIENT_ID=123456
```

And you can use this as:

```
console.log(process.env.API_CLIENT_ID)
```

Please follow the documentation for more details.

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Comment: Ok! according to documentation I made a `.env` file at root then I made `key=value` as `VUE_APP_CLIENTID="2"` then in `src/App.vue` I used this command `client_id: process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENTID,` and I am getting undefined.

Comment: @InYourFace you are running `vue-cli-service build` ?

Comment: no I don't know what it is, and if I try to put your command in CMD it says `'vue-cli-service' is not recognized`

Comment: @InYourFace updated solution to add support for the `non-cli` projects of Vue.js... check #1.

Comment: I have seen a tutorial in which he used your #1 approach but this file is accessible, is it not??

Comment: Yes, just make sure...  your `App.vue` & `config.js` are on same level... else you'll have to use the relative path... if having different folder.

Comment: Thanks for your responses but the major concern is security I am very disappointed with Vue JS not providing security. And then there's no need of config.js if there's no security we can just put all credentials into app.vue. again thanks bro❤️ accepting your answer.

Comment: isn't the non cli solution making the (secret) key availlable in the frontend??